# How to create MQTT secure channel using TLS-PSK cipher suit in android

Tags: java, android, iot

I am implementing an app which requires MQTT communication should be secure in P2P local mode (No internet connectivity only both device and application connects to router). So I have decided to use TLS-PSK cipher based handshake mechanism.

I have tried with Android native support PSKKeyManager but there are not enough references to create that Channel.
Other options like bouncy castle need to explore.

Please help how can we use TLS-PSK cipher along with MQTT.